# Most popular arabic culture for website localization

Tags: localization, locale, arabic, arabic-support

I have created a website and I would like to provide locale support with arabic culture. When I see the locale strings there are many culture codes for arabic. Which one is best to use in my website for arabic language?

```
ar-DZ   Arabic - Algeria
ar-BH   Arabic - Bahrain
ar-EG   Arabic - Egypt  
ar-IQ   Arabic - Iraq
ar-JO   Arabic - Jordan
ar-KW   Arabic - Kuwait 
ar-LB   Arabic - Lebanon
ar-LY   Arabic - Libya
ar-MA   Arabic - Morocco
ar-OM   Arabic - Oman
ar-QA   Arabic - Qatar
ar-SA   Arabic - Saudi 
ar-SY   Arabic - Syria  
ar-TN   Arabic - Tunisia
ar-AE   Arabic - United Arab Emirates
ar-YE   Arabic - Yemen
```

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is not to specify a particular country and use just `ar` (if allowed by your localization framework).